# How to get input value in a table's td on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I have a dynamic table and there is an input field in each row as well as a respective button on every rows. I want to get the respective value of the input field when I click on the respective button. To replicate the scenario, you may refer to the following static code with two rows. Can someone help?

```js
$(".returnItem").click(function(){
    var row = $(this).closest("input").find("input[name='newQty']").val(); //This is not working
    var row = $(".newQty").val(); //This is not working also
    alert(row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="assignOaForm" name="assignOaForm">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Part Number</th>
          <th scope="col">Name of Item</th>
          <th scope="col">Description</th>
          <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
          <th scope="col">New Quantity</th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>xxxxxxxxxxx</td>
          <td>name1</td>
          <td>description1</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <input class="form-control oldQty" type="number" name="oldQty" value="10" hidden readonly>
          <td><input class="form-control newQty" type="number" name="newQty"></td>
          <div class="container text-center">
            <td><button type="submit" name="addItem" class="btn btn-success addItem" >Add <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button></td>
            <td><button type="submit" name="returnItem" class="btn btn-info returnItem" >Return <i class="fas fa-undo-alt"></i></button></td>
          </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>yyyyyyyyyy</td>
          <td>name2</td>
          <td>description2</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <input class="form-control oldQty" type="number" name="oldQty" value="20" hidden readonly>
          <td><input class="form-control newQty" type="number" name="newQty"></td>
          <div class="container text-center">
            <td><button type="submit" name="addItem" class="btn btn-success addItem" >Add <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button></td>
            <td><button type="submit" name="returnItem" class="btn btn-info returnItem" >Return <i class="fas fa-undo-alt"></i></button></td>
          </div>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `.closest()` only traverses upwards. And there is no `<input>` that wrapps around your `<button>` so this is never found. Use something like `.closest('tr')`, then you will have the `<tr>` and can work your way down from there.

Comment: Also, a lot of your elements have multiple class declaration. If you able to fix it, do it. It can cause css or javascript code not working as you intended to.

Comment: @RickyStefano Thanks for pointing out. Just corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you are using jQuery 1.2.3, which doesn't contains `closest` function (added since 1.3). Although, you're not looking for function `closest`, but `parents`. By this function, you will find parent `<tr>`, and then by `find` you will find the input and get his value via `val`.

Also, since your buttons are inside form, after pressing the button, form will be submitted, so you need to add `e.preventDefault()` from preventing the form to be sent.

```js
$(".returnItem").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  row = $(this).parents("tr").find("input[name='newQty']").val();
  alert(row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="assignOaForm" name="assignOaForm">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Part Number</th>
          <th scope="col">Name of Item</th>
          <th scope="col">Description</th>
          <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
          <th scope="col">New Quantity</th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>xxxxxxxxxxx</td>
          <td>name1</td>
          <td>description1</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <input class="form-control" type="number" class="oldQty" name="oldQty" value="10" hidden readonly>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="number" class="newQty" name="newQty"></td>
          <div class="container text-center">
            <td><button type="submit" name="addItem" class="btn btn-success addItem" >Add <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button></td>
            <td><button type="submit" name="returnItem" class="btn btn-info returnItem" >Return <i class="fas fa-undo-alt"></i></button></td>
          </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>yyyyyyyyyy</td>
          <td>name2</td>
          <td>description2</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <input class="form-control" type="number" class="oldQty" name="oldQty" value="20" hidden readonly>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="number" class="newQty" name="newQty"></td>
          <div class="container text-center">
            <td><button type="submit" name="addItem" class="btn btn-success addItem" >Add <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button></td>
            <td><button type="submit" name="returnItem" class="btn btn-info returnItem" >Return <i class="fas fa-undo-alt"></i></button></td>
          </div>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You have used `type="submit"` in button which led to refresh in
   jquery fetching data there are many options below given is one of
   them.
2. Use latest version of jquery cdn for using `closest` and `find` based functions. https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery

```js
$(".returnItem").click(function(){
    var row = $(this).parent().prev().prev().children().val(); 
    alert(row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="assignOaForm" name="assignOaForm">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Part Number</th>
          <th scope="col">Name of Item</th>
          <th scope="col">Description</th>
          <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
          <th scope="col">New Quantity</th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>xxxxxxxxxxx</td>
          <td>name1</td>
          <td>description1</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <input class="form-control" type="number" class="oldQty" name="oldQty" value="10" hidden readonly>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="number" class="newQty" name="newQty"></td>
            <td><button type="button" name="addItem" class="btn btn-success addItem" >Add <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button></td>
            <td><button type="button" name="returnItem" class="btn btn-info returnItem" >Return <i class="fas fa-undo-alt"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>yyyyyyyyyy</td>
          <td>name2</td>
          <td>description2</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <input class="form-control" type="number" class="oldQty" name="oldQty" value="20" hidden readonly>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="number" class="newQty" name="newQty"></td>
            <td><button type="button" name="addItem" class="btn btn-success addItem" >Add <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button></td>
            <td><button type="button" name="returnItem" class="btn btn-info returnItem" >Return <i class="fas fa-undo-alt"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```